# How to write the output of powershell query to txt or csv file?

Tags: powershell

I have a query to reserve bulk IPaddress but can't find a way to write the output to a txt or csv file. I have tried using export-csv and out-file cmdlets but it does not work.

```
Foreach ($line in (Import-Csv -header Scope,IP,MAC,Hostname  -Path C:\temp\NewDHCP.csv))
{
    Add-DhcpServerv4Reservation -ComputerName dhcp server-ScopeId $line.scope -IPAddress $line.IP -ClientId $line.MAC -HostName $line.hostname -Description "Reservation for Printer"| outfile c:\temp\result.txt
}
```

Result.txt file is empty.

Would like to see the output was the reservation done successfully or was there an error.

Comment: It is probably worth noting that you can change `outfile` to `add-content` and this script should work as intended to see successful entries. Keep in mind that what is returned by `Add-DhcpServerv4Reservation` is an object with a number of properties, not just a string, so it might not output very nicely by default, especially since it is just a WMI wrapper. See [TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj590686.aspx), specifically the Output section. If you want errors in your file add ` 2>&1` just before your pipe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the `Out-File` outside the foreach brackets:

```
Foreach($line in $stuff) {Do-Stuff $line} | Out-File c:\temp\result.txt
```

If you leave `Out-File` inside the `foreach` loop, the default behavior will overwrite the file each iteration.

Also, make sure that the script does in fact return data to the console if you remove `Out-File`

**Edit**

Mike is right, the previous command will not pipe out.
I usually do foreach like this, which does work:

```
$stuff | %{Do-Stuff $_} | Out-File c:\temp\result.txt
```

Comment: What you use is short for `ForEach-Object` and does actually function differently than a `ForEach` loop. Also, while you can not pipe from a `ForEach` loop, you can assign the output to a variable, and then pipe that.

Comment: Never realized there was a difference. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Mostly just a FYI but what you have should have worked but there might be two points worth mentioning:

1. I hope its just a typo but in the question you have `OutFile` which should just be `Out-File`
2. Moving the logging outside the loop is a good idea but for the way you have it just adding the `-Append` switch might have gotten you the results you are looking for. Also `-Encoding ASCII` depending on your output.

I am not familiar with the cmdlet `Add-DhcpServerv4Reservation` but this would all work as long as the results are sent to standard output.

Answer (score 0):

@Jon is close, but you can't pipe a foreach loop like that.

You can enclose it in $(), though.  It's kind of nasty to look at, but it works.

```
$(Foreach ($line in (Import-Csv -header Scope,IP,MAC,Hostname  -Path C:\temp\NewDHCP.csv))
{
    Add-DhcpServerv4Reservation -ComputerName dhcp server-ScopeId $line.scope -IPAddress $line.IP -ClientId $line.MAC -HostName $line.hostname -Description "Reservation for Printer" 
} ) | out-file c:\temp\result.txt
```

Comment: "you can't pipe a foreach loop like that".  Sure you can, I do it all the time.

Comment: Nvm, looks like it doesn't work with `Foreach`.  I always use `%{}`, and it works fine with that.  Strange